# cannot create std::vector larger than max_size() for size below max_size

Tags: c++, stdvector, google-benchmark

I am running google benchmark for some basic cache testing and I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'

what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()
```

However, I am printing the max_size and the actual size (see below) and while the max_size equals 2^60-1 it breaks at 2^28. What am I missing?

The benchmark code is below. The code is compiled using Clang 11 with c++20.

```
static void bm_std_vector_in_cache_double(benchmark::State& state)
{
  auto constexpr d{3.1415};

  auto const bytes = (2 << state.range(0)) * 1024;
  auto data = std::vector<double>(bytes / sizeof(double), d);
  std::cout << data.max_size() << '\n';
  std::cout << data.size() << '\n';
  for (auto _ : state){
      auto sum = 0.0;
      for(auto j = 0; j < data.size(); ++j)
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum += data[j] * data[j]);
    }

  state.SetBytesProcessed(state.iterations() * data.size());
}

BENCHMARK(bm_std_vector_in_cache_double)->DenseRange(1, 20);
```

Comment: does break at `2^28` or is that the last size for which it works? Better print `max_` and requested size before you attempt to create the vector so you can see more easily where is goes off

Comment: 2^27 is the last size that works.

Comment: That error message is pretty badly chosen. The failure is happening because you can't allocate a contiguous block at 2^28 elements or more. But the usefulness (more accurately, the lack thereof) of `max_size` itself is arguable. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867206/practical-use-of-vectormax-size)

Comment: Did you expect to achieve `2^60-1`?

Comment: @WhozCraig Shouldn't that throw `std::bad_alloc` instead of `std::length_error`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You would think. Like I said, that's a terrible message.

Comment: `auto const bytes = (2 << state.range(0)) * 1024;` What is the type of this? (yeah almost always auto).

Comment: bingo! The AAA got me here. auto const bytes is of type const int. auto const bytes = .... 1024L; creates a long allows for longer vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that the type of bytes was an int.

```
auto const bytes = (2 << state.range(0)) * 1024;
```

changing to

```
auto const bytes = (2 << state.range(0)) * 1024L;
```

changes it to a long allowing for longer vectors and even better better unsigned long long:

```
auto const bytes = (2 << state.range(0)) * 1024ULL;
```

Comment: Better still, 2ULL.